# Gave my mobile number out online. Now I'm being spammed?

Tags: phone

Long story short, I thought this site would boost my snap chat score.
I had to do dozens of surveys and competitions, put in my mobile number, and it didn't even boost my score.

Okay, we've established OP is an idiot. **Can we please just drop it?**

The thing is, now I'm being spammed probably about 20 times a day. 20 phonecalls from 8:00am to 12:00pm, people trying to sell me stuff, give me money I've been overcharged with ect...

**Edit: 2 of them rang me while writing this question!**

Even more worryingly I'm getting texts that seem to say I've been entered into some kind of draw:

> Click to Win and iPhone6 Grab your chance, click now! Opt out: 123456

I don't know what to do. **Is it possible for these people to charge me? All I gave them is my mobile phone number?**

Another text:

> Are you our laser eye surgery winer. Reply YES to claim your prize! Opt out: reply stop

I wanted to reply STOP but my phone warned me that sending STOP (or any message to this number) could cost me more than what's being provided. So now I'm sitting here, not opting out, getting these texts.

*Questions:*

**What I'm really worried about is will I get a giant phone bill? I signed up to dozens of surveys and competitions, no way can I find them again, now way can I find out how to opt out of them all? Will I be charged? How do I stop this/appeal? Can I talk to my provider?**

**How do I block these texts and phone calls?**

Comment: If you have prepaid: burn the number. The only money lost is the money still on the card. If you have a subscription it gets worse. Contact your provider.

Answer (score 0):

You can opt-out but it seems that it doesn't help. The companies calling you are most likely different ones each time. If it is the normal survey sites they sell your details on.

I would suggest downloading a blacklisting app or get a new number.

Comment: I'm more worried about a giant phone bill. I'm worried about these competitions I've apparently entered...what can they do with my phone number?